Import typescript source code file (not transpiled code) in ionic app from node_modules package
I want to know if it's possible (not talking about: is it a "good practice") in an Ionic application to directly import typescript source code files from an installed module in node_modules folder, and treat them like common "src" files, which means they should be compiled or webpacked or whatever, like any other local source file.
So, I'm not talking about a typical npm module, which usually contains "packed" javascript code inside a "dist" folder, optionally using declaration files.
My final goal is installing a module which acts like a local library, being able to directly see and EDIT (for developing purpose) source code (then updates should be moved to the library and republished etc.).
To make a c# comparison, it should act like a class library (.csproj) which can be loaded into different solutions (.sln): any solution can edit and rebuild the class library.
Basically, these are my requirements:

I want to directly import only typescript source code, not javascript compiled code.
I can't use a local library, pointing to a folder like "../../mylib" and using npm link or something like that.
The final app will be built in external platforms like Ionic Appflow, so everything must be included in dependencies or scripts.

Is this possible just handling webpack configuration? (and how?)
This is my package example.
After running npm install ansh_ioniclibrarytest I'm able to import some test code like this:
import { SayHello } from 'ansh_ioniclibrarytest';

...

console.log(new SayHello().sayHelloString());

Of course I'm getting an error
"TypeError: ansh_ioniclibrarytest__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_25__.SayHello is not a constructor"
I tried some edits to package.json "files" properties or tsconfig.json "include", "paths", "files" properties without any result. For example in tsconfig.json:
"include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "node_modules/ansh_ioniclibrarytest/**/*.ts"
    ],

A similar question could be: (Reddit) Can I publish 100% TypeScript code only? (but I did not found any working example)

Can you specify the source file in the import (with extension)? Or, you can specify loader plugins with node that would allow for resolving a package import to a specific file, and that is probably possible with webpack.

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#loaders

@ZachSmith Thanks your comment. I don't really understand the first part. Do you mean if I'm able to import the class directly from the source file, with something like import * as h from 'node_modules/ansh_ioniclibrarytest/src/say-hello'; and then use it like console.log(new h.SayHello().sayHelloString());? I tried but it has the same result. I'm not able to specificy the file extension in the import, I tried to specificy allowImportingTsExtensions in compiler options but i get an Unknown compiler option 'allowImportingTsExtensions' error.

@ZachSmith For the second part (loader plugin) could you elaborate a bit more? I tried to read some docs but I don't really understand [I will open a new bounty request if needed to get some help]
